# Open any Application if a particular Device is connected using Javascript Button

Tags: javascript

Please i need a javascript code button, to check how many devices are connected to the Laptop, and if a particular or certain device is connected Let it open any  application.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can do this with JavaScript due to security restrictions and API limitations. I guess that you're looking for some Java solution.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, But what script does apple use, that if an ipad or iphone is connected to Mac it should open iTunes application?

Comment: @KingAmada — That's a native application running on the client. It isn't limited by browser sand boxes. (On the subject of which, you probably could do this with JS … just not in a browser … and you would have to involve native APIs at some point … which might require writing a library for your JS engine in C or another language with access to native APIs).

Comment: But can you help me with a javascript code to check how many devices are connected to the laptop if possible?

Comment: @KingAmada There's absolutely no way to do this with JavaScript. JS cannot deal with OS APIs. Write C/C++/Java/Python application for this.